# Java Reflection to load classes

Tags: java, reflection

I am given an external folder called "ATM".

In the folder, it only contains files that ends with .class.

How would I load it?

I've been using Class.forName. It does not work.

I need to load it to use Java's reflection on it.

Comment: Do you know the package name (needed by `Class.forName`) of the class you want to load? In general, please know the details of classes you are loading. What if they end up doing bad things?

Answer (score 2):

You have basically two options:

1. make sure the folder is in the class path when you start the program
2. create an `java.net.URLClassLoader` to load the classes

Comment: What does "class path" means?

Comment: You can specify it when yoou start your program: `java -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files> ...`